# Python: Share a python object instance between child processes

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, subprocess

I want to share a python class instance between my child processes that are created with the subprocess.Popen
How can I do it ? What arguments should I use of the Popen?

Comment: You can't, really. The new processes don't have access to your address spaces, even if they are executing Python scripts. The only datatype you can use to communicate between arbitrary processes is a stream of bytes (via a file, a socket, etc). If you are using `Popen` to run the *same* script, you can use something like the `multiprocessing` module to facilitate that communication.

Answer (score 0):

You can share a pickle over a named pipe.

Comment: cant really pickle the object, as loading and saving would take much time

Comment: Your task seems unpythonian, sorry. Too tight OS integration.